# what is the meaning of the first line in the below kotlin code. Newbee to Kotlin from Java

Tags: kotlin

I am a Java programmer and new to Kotlin. Please help me understand the below code, especially the first line.

```
class SiteListEventBus : EventBus<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent, String, NotificationHandler<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent>>() {

    data class SiteListChangeEvent(val entityId: String, val routingKey: String)

    override fun getSubscriptionKey(event: SiteListChangeEvent?): String {
        return event!!.routingKey
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I read the first line:

1. `class SiteListEventBus`
   Define a new class.
2. `: FooBar()`
   [Extend the class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance) `FooBar` using the empty constructor.
3. `FooBar` is actually `EventBus<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent, String, NotificationHandler<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent>>`
   Generics apply here the way you would expect in Java.
4. `class SiteListEventBus : FooBar() {`
   Begin implementing the `SiteListEventBus` class.

Here is how I read the rest:

1. `data class SiteListChangeEvent(val entityId: String, val routingKey: String)`
   Create a [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).
2. `override fun getSubscriptionKey`
   The `override` is similar to the `@Override` annotation. Override the method `getSubscriptionKey`.
3. `event!!.routingKey`
   The `event` variable is nullable. I recommend [reading about the `!!` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am trying to rewrite this class to Java, but unsuccessful. Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

```
class SiteListEventBus :EventBus<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent, String, 

NotificationHandler<SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent>>()  {
```

So from what im gathering here EventBus would be like your base class which SiteListEventBus is inheriting from and EventBus which conforms to or includes 3 type parameters

Which are SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent as type 1, 
String as type 2, 
then NotificationHandler as type 3 which then has a type parameter of SiteListEventBus.SiteListChangeEvent little complicated there

```
data class SiteListChangeEvent(val entityId: String, val routingKey: String)
```

This data class then would just be the parameters/variables SiteListChangeEvent which would be your entityId of type string and your routingKey of type string

```
override fun getSubscriptionKey(event: SiteListChangeEvent?): String {
    return event!!.routingKey
}
```

this last method overrides your getter for subscription key passes in your event which is SiteListChangeEvent? which is an optional value from the ? (so this can be null) to be used and its expecting a String for a return type

then your returning your passed in event!!.routingKey. the not-null assertion operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null.

So, you can write event!!, and this will return a non-null value of event (e.g., a String in your example) or throw a null pointer exception if event is null:   soooo this seems like a bad idea because if event is null this will crash for sure

if you need further explanation let me know and ill go into further detail

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful. I am trying to rewrite this code in Java but I am not able to do that. Would be grateful if you can help me with this.

Comment: not sure why you would want to rewrite it in java you should be converting all your other stuff to kotlin